# RewriteBase needed when using mod_alias

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

In my apache config i created an alias:

```
<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /projecten "C:/Users/Youri/SkyDrive/Projecten"
</IfModule>

<Directory "C:/Users/Youri/SkyDrive/Projecten">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride FileInfo Options

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In the folder 'projecten/mvc' i have a .htacces file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

When i go to my browser http://localhost/projecten/mvc/ i get an error with the message:

*The requested URL /Users/Youri/SkyDrive/Projecten/mvc/public/ was not found on this server.*

When i copy the folder (mvc) to my document root and i navigate to http://localhost/mvc/ the rewrite works..

When i add to the htaccess file in my projects folder:

```
RewriteBase /projecten/mvc
```

It works, but i dont want to add a RewriteBase because when i place it in the document root i dont need it...

Can somebody tell me what is going wrong?

*Apache/2.4.10 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1j PHP/5.6.4 configured*

Comment: Nothing is going wrong; you _need_ to specify a RewriteBase simply because it is required for things to work correctly under the setup you are using.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase: _“This directive is **required** when you use a relative path in a substitution in per-directory (htaccess) context unless either of the following conditions are true: The original request, and the substitution, are underneath the DocumentRoot (as opposed to reachable by other means, such as Alias). [Or] The filesystem path to the directory containing the RewriteRule, suffixed by the relative substitution is also valid as a URL path on the server (this is rare).”_

Comment: _“(as opposed to reachable by other means, such as Alias)”_ is exactly what you have here, and so you need to specify the RewriteBase since you are also using a relative path in your substitution … works exactly as documented.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is “going wrong” here. You need to specify a `RewriteBase` simply because it is required for things to work correctly under the setup you are using.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase:

> This directive is *required* when you use a relative path in a substitution in per-directory (htaccess) context unless either of the following conditions are true:
>   - The original request, and the substitution, are underneath the DocumentRoot (as opposed to reachable by other means, such as Alias).
>   - The filesystem path to the directory containing the RewriteRule, suffixed by the relative substitution is also valid as a URL path on the server (this is rare).”

*“(as opposed to reachable by other means, such as Alias)”* is exactly what you have here, and so you need to specify the RewriteBase since you are also using a relative path in your substitution.